ps не выводит полное имя приложения в Arch Linux
Мне для утилиты нужно получить:
полное имя процесса (НЕ абсолютный путь к процессу), pid процесса, пользователь, запустивший процесс, потребление cpu процессом и потребление оперативной памяти процессом.
Я использовал:
ps -e --no-headers -o pid,rss,pcpu,comm,user

Но выводит только первые 15 символов названия процесса.
Например:
Должно вывести:
98398  5608  0.0 systemd-userworker root

А вывод:
98398  5608  0.0 systemd-userwor root

Как вывести полное имя процесса?

А в comm просто нет ничего дальше. Попробуйте comm:30 и там тоже будет обрезок.  Собственно я вижу только kworker/... которые показывают больше 15 символов. Может вам надо command?

@AlexeyTen да, нужен именно comm:30, можно было бы не комментарием, а ответом. Спасибо!

Чтобы сделать вывод шире - нужно использовать следующее:
ps -e --no-headers -o pid,rss,pcpu,comm:32,user

comm:32 - вывод названия с ограничением в 32 символа. Параметр :32 применим ко всем выводам (pid, rss, pcpu и тому подобные). Вместо 32 можно использовать своё значение.
В большинстве систем Linux длина имени процесса (argv[0]) ограничена. Рекомендуется использовать значение, не превышающее 255 символов для поля comm.
